# What was the justification of morality in Puritan antinomianism?

Tags: religion, contemporary-history

As far as I know, Puritans were [devout Calvinists](http://historyproject.ucdavis.edu/lessons/view_lesson.php?id=8). [According to Theopedia](http://www.theopedia.com/Antinomianism), it is associated with disobedience to the established authority, so it may be connected with the idea of lawlessness, immorality, or licentiousness. Was this term merely a pejorative adjective for people who disagreed with the established religious authority, like *legalism*? Or did the Puritan antinomians really have their own theology on justification before God, and if so, how did the Puritan antinomians thought they were justified? What was the purpose of God's moral laws then?

Comment: Wrong forum, try http://christianity.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: "It is associated" ?  What is associated?  I am confused.

Comment: I thought it had something to do with history.

Comment: @DoubleU Questions about religious theory and doctrine are not in scope here, unless they have some immediate and pertinent bearing on a historical event, which is not the case here. So, you should either be asking on http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/ or on the Christianity SE I already linked.

Comment: D'oh. I should have just directly asked about Anne Hutchinson. She was involved in the antinomian controversy, and she was accused of being antinomian. Would a question about Anne Hutchinson's beliefs be on topic here?

Comment: If it's about theology, it's still better to ask it at the two SE's Tyler Durden mentioned.